# React Context and ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

If I have an ES6 class,

```
export default class WSConn {
    constructor() {
        this.conn = null;
        this.event_id = null
        this.navigator = null;
    }

    getEventID() {
        return this.event_id
    }

    setEventID(event_id) {
        this.event_id = event_id
    }
}
```

and I pass it in to context (and initialize it),

```
class ContextProvider extends Component {
    getChildContext() {
        return {
            logger: new appLogger(Platform.OS),
            websocket: new WSConn()
        };
    } 

    render() {
        return this.props.children
    }
}

ContextProvider.childContextTypes = {
  websocket: React.PropTypes.object
};

function wrapWithContextProvider(Comp) {
  return (props) => {
    return (
        <ContextProvider>
            <Comp {...props} />
        </ContextProvider>
    );
  };
}
```

and I set data in the class, why when I then get the data, is it still null?

How do I set and store data in an es6 class that I pass around via react context without losing any of the state? Or should I just be keeping this as a global object?

Comment: What code sets the data? If it happens in an asynchronous callback, you will need to restructure your code.

Comment: Any component that gets it from context. So I have a component that is wrapped in this context, I execute `this.context.websocket.setEventID(id)`, then if I run from that component, or another component that has this context, `this.context.websocket.getEventID()`, it returns null

Comment: Please show a [mcve] so that the problem is reproducible.

Comment: Well it works here: http://mikelambert.me/react/#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

Comment: So not sure what is going on in my native app.

Comment: So instead of initializing the classes in the getChildContext, I initialized them outside of it and passed the instances in, and it's working fine.

Comment: @NathanHyland I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. Please create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem. When you have solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I was doing this:

```
class SomeClass extends Component {
    getChildContext() {
    return {
        monitor: new Monitoring(url)
    }
  }
}

class Monitoring {
    constructor(url) {
    this.url = url
  }
  getUrl() {
    return this.url
  }
}
```

Instead of this:

```
class SomeClass extends Component {
    constructor() {
    this.monitor = new Monitoring(url)
  }

    getChildContext() {
    return {
        monitor: this.monitor
    }
  }
}

class Monitoring {
    constructor(url) {
    this.url = url
  }
  getUrl() {
    return this.url
  }
}
```